# How to put "List View Actions in Lightning Experience" into metadata?

Tags: metadata, list-view, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I've defined "List View Actions in Lightning Experience" using Setup -> Object Manager -> (my custom object) -> Search Layouts -> List View -> List View Actions in Lightning Experience, but I can't find a way to put this into metadata files. There is a searchLayouts section in .object file, but List View Actions are not there when I retrieve metadata from the org. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm) of **44.0** API saying that lightning list view actions are mentioned in `massQuickActions` tag in  `searchLayout` section of object. Example from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_searchlayouts.htm)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    . . .
    <searchLayouts>
        <listViewButtons>New</listViewButtons>
        <listViewButtons>Accept</listViewButtons>
        <listViewButtons>ChangeOwner</listViewButtons>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>firstQuote__c</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>finalQuote__c</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <massQuickActions>Create_MQA_Contact</massQuickActions>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>CREATEDBY_USER</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
    </searchLayouts>
    . . .
</CustomObject>
```

so if you have **Winter '19** org, your `package.xml` should contains the following:

```
<types>
    <members>YourObjectname.YourQuickActionName</members>
    <name>QuickAction</name>
</types>

<types>
    <members>YourObjectname</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<version>44.0</version>
```

you have to include quick action and object in your `package.xml` file